# Splitting an external array to give different titles

Tags: php, json

I've been trying to figure out how to split the array and add different titles for each of the separate titles on the page, for each of the different things that this displays. However the most I can manage to do is add a comma between the numbers and words.

I would like to add `selling"1st variable price"second variable"` etc however I don't quite know how to do anything other than to turn this very confusing looking bunch of letters:

> user name and notes 01001000013972583957ecCCany amount-w378- v west

into anything other than this:

> 0,100,10000,1397258395,7ec,CC,any amount-w378- v west

Also, this is what it looks like in its JSON form:

```
{"selling":"0","quantity":"100","price":"10000","date":"1397258395","rs_name":"7ec","contact":"CC","notes":"any amount-w378- v west"}
```

I just want all the information that is in there to displayed like that however I'm not quite sure how to add the titles that is in the JSON data. I also don't have access to the external site to change anything.

A little background: what I am trying to achieve is a price look-up for a game on my website from an external site. I tried to use an `iframe` but it was terrible; I would rather just manually display it rather than showing their site from mine - their style and my style clash terribly.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://forums.zybez.net/runescape-2007-prices/api/rune+axe');



$obj = json_decode($json,true);



$blah1 = implode( $obj[0]["offers"][1]);
print_r($blah1);
```

Comment: It would be better if you tell us how your expected output should be.

Comment: I don't see an array in your JSON, I just see one object. And there's nothing labeled `offers`.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but maybe you just need `foreach ($obj as $title => $value)` and have this print each field in the JSON?

Comment: (When posting questions, please don't use all-lower-case, and if you can run it through a spell-checker it makes it more readable for everyone. It doesn't need to be poetry, but effort towards ease of reading is appreciated. Thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

If you know where it is, you should be able to just grab it and show it out?

You can use a failsafe to check if it is present with `is_array()` and `isset()` functions - see php.net docs on them.

Your `print_r` should give you good valid info -- try to wrap it around `<pre></pre>` tags before for better readability or view the source - it will be easier!

```
<pre><?php print_r($obj) ?></pre>
```

This should be your starting point, and from here you will either take the first one of your items or loop through all with

```
foreach ($obj as $o) { //should be $objects, not $obj
//do whatever with $o, like echo $o['price'] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each `offers` row is a `table` with each field separated by row:

```
$item = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://forums.zybez.net/runescape-2007-prices/api/rune+axe'));

while ($offer = array_shift($item[0]->offers)) {
    echo "<table>" . PHP_EOL;

    foreach ($offer as $field => $value) {
        echo "<tr><th>$field</th><td>$value</td></tr>" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo "</table>" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

http://codepad.org/C3PQJHqL

Tables in HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/G5QqZ/